# How do I login to AWS EC2 with only a public ip address, username, and password?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I have received a Public IP, Username, and Password for an EC2 instance I need to deploy a Node API backend to, but I'm not able to ssh into it. When I try to SSH into it, I get the following message:

```
ssh: connect to host xx.xxx.xxx.xx port 22: Connection timed out
```

And if I try to ping the IP address, I receive a timeout as well:

```
Pinging xx.xxx.xxx.xx with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
```

Usually I get a pem file, but I wasn't provided with one on this project. Are those always required for AWS EC2 connections and maybe they just forgot to provide me with it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What command do you use to connect to the server?

Comment: ssh <username>@<ipaddress> 
I've also tried just straight ssh <ipaddress> and get the same "Connection timed out" response

Comment: Please try to run `ssh -v server-ip` and see what output you see in the terminal

Comment: It sounds like the firewall/security group attached to the EC2 instance is not allowing your connection. You should reach out to the person that gave you the login information and ask them to add your IP address to the security group.

Comment: @Dream Bold OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.4.3
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
ssh: Could not resolve hostname server-ip: No such host is known.
 
If I remove the server-ip part, I get the same error message mentioned in the original question.

Comment: Here we are using 'exit 0' as the remote command to be called on successful SSH

`# ssh -q -o BatchMode=yes  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=5 server2 'exit 0'`
` echo $?`
While if the output exit status is `non-zero` so we know the test SSH connection has failed

`# ssh -q -o BatchMode=yes  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=5 server2 'exit 0'`
`# echo $?`
Output: 255

Comment: I think you might be correct, @Mark B. I've reached out and asked the provider to confirm they added my public IP address to the whitelist.

Comment: You should replace the `server-ip` with the provided server IP @Rob

Comment: You can check if the `ssh` connection is available with the commands I have provided above `ssh -q -o Batchmode...` If it's running, you'd better check the firewall from the client

Comment: OMG haha, should have figured that out. Thanks @Dream Bold. Just figured it all out. The provider didn't have something set correctly on his side. "The route table did not have the internet gateway set." I'm able to get in now.

Comment: So the issue was on the client side, right? @Rob

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be an issue on the AWS configuration side. The route table did not have the internet gateway set.